# WPF OnMouseOver Style MenuItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, mouseover, menuitem

I am relatively new to WPF I am trying to change the Hover effect of the menu item and set it similar to the one of my buttons in the Toolbar.

I am left with a double border when I hover on the menu most probably from the MenuItem. How can I remove it?

XAML File:

```
     <ToolBarTray Style="{StaticResource MainToolBar}">
            <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Width="Auto" Padding="0" Background="Transparent" Name="Tool">
                <Button Content="Button 1"/>
                <Button Content="Button 2"/>
                <Separator/>
                <Menu Margin="0, -1, 0, 0" Style="{StaticResource Menu}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu">
                        <MenuItem Header="File">
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </ToolBar>
           </ToolBarTray>
```

Resource File:

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                     HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                     VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ToolBarBKHover}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Menu" TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ToolBarBKHover}"/>
                </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: and where do you set the over effect of your menu item ? Please show some code. 'it doesn't work' = ??  Please elaborate.

Comment: I didn't put the code in here as I tried quit a while and didn't manage to get it working.

I'm using the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'double border' issue cannot be solve at the Menu level : you have to dig further and redefine a template / Trigger for the MenuItem of your menu. MenuItem (not *Menu*) has default behaviour of turning its Border color to grey on MouseOver, and that is what you want to change.

Edit : so, for instance, you might define a default style for MenuItem with a setter on BorderWidth = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your menu items in a `Listbox`, and when you move over your mouse you want colors to change.  Here is a simple way to do it, but I have copied the code from my existing project:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#58290a" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Lucida Console" />
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
          <GradientStop Color="#feca00" Offset="0.1"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#ffe100" Offset="0.4"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#feca00" Offset="0.6"/>
          <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.9"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
        <Setter.Value>
          <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Red" GlowSize="4"/>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

hope this helps